# Which solution has better performance: StringBuilder or String Interpolation-Concatenation

Tags: string, scala, stringbuilder, string-interpolation

I am writing files to disk using Scala.

To create the whole String that will be written to the file, I am currently iterating over my data and appending all the information to a StringBuilder object.

for instance:

```
val moreData = getMoreData
strBuilder.append(moreData)
strBuilder.append("even more data")
//...
strBuilder.toString
```

At the end of the operation I then call the StringBuilder's toString method, and write to the Path.

I know Scala has compilation optimizations for Strings, so my questions are:

Which approach has the better performance. String-Interpolation-Concatenation or StringBuilder?

Are these compilation optimizations somehow related to StringBuilder? In other words, are there optimizations for StringBuilder append operation?

Comment: You don't say what you mean by interpolator-concat. `s"$foo" + s"$bar"`? or `s"$foo$bar"`?

Comment: I meant something more like this: s"$foo" + s"$bar"

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda - Why would you do that instead of `s"$foo$bar"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String interpolation concatenation uses a `StringBuilder` to generate its results.  It would be possible to optimize string interpolation more, but as it stands it is mostly designed for expressive power, not performance.  You should use `StringBuilder` if you know that string creation is going to be limiting, and it's not too hard to do so.  If you *don't* know, or you know that it isn't a major issue, string interpolation is usually much easier to read, so you should prefer it in most instances.

Comment: The `f""` macro will always be able to emit more intelligent code than `s""`. f==fast, s==slow, apparently. The OP asks about string construction, but if you're writing to a file, you could be better off writing chunks. That i/o could outweigh how you build the data buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to concatenate multiple strings will be using `StringBuilder`.

But your task is not about string concatenation. The most efficient way to write multiple strings to file is using good old java's `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter`:

```
val fw = new FileWriter("foo.out")
val bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)

strings.foreach {
  s =>
    bw.write(s)
}

bw.close()
fw.close()
```

Optionally you can wrap `BufferedWriter` with `PrintWriter` if you need formatting functionality.

Of course everything above is true if you prefer performance over code size.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following test program in VB.NET, and was a bit surprised that string concatenation is faster than both interpolated strings and stringbuilder. However obviously stringbuilder will start to win when more appends are made, as the final three tests show.

```vb
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim sw As New Stopwatch

        sw.Start()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000

            Dim s As String = "DateModified=" & GetString("@auditdatemodified") & ",UserModifiedID = " & GetString("@audituseroptionsid")
            If s = "" Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If

        Next

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("concat " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

        sw = New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000

            Dim s As String = $"DateModified={GetString("@auditdatemodified")},UserModifiedID = {GetString("@audituseroptionsid")}"
            If s = "" Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If


        Next

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("interp " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

        sw = New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000

            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb.Append("DateModified=").Append(GetString("@auditdatemodified")).Append(",UserModifiedID = ").Append(GetString("@audituseroptionsid"))
            Dim s As String = sb.ToString
            If s = "" Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If

        Next

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("builder " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

        sw = New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000

            Dim s As String = "DateModified=" & GetString("@auditdatemodified") & ",UserModifiedID = " & GetString("@audituseroptionsid")
            For j As Integer = 1 To 100
                s = s & GetString("hello world")
            Next
            If s = "" Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If

        Next

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("concat many " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

        sw = New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000

            Dim s As String = $"DateModified={GetString("@auditdatemodified")},UserModifiedID = {GetString("@audituseroptionsid")}"
            For j As Integer = 1 To 100
                s = $"{s}{GetString("hello world")}"
            Next
            If s = "" Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If


        Next

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("interp many " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

        sw = New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000

            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb.Append("DateModified=").Append(GetString("@auditdatemodified")).Append(",UserModifiedID = ").Append(GetString("@audituseroptionsid"))
            For j As Integer = 1 To 100
                sb.Append(GetString("hello world"))
            Next
            Dim s As String = sb.ToString
            If s = "" Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If

        Next

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("builder many " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Private Function GetString(s) As String

        Return s

    End Function

End Module
```

The results on my PC (latest core i7 13 series) :

```
concat 86
interp 150
builder 178
concat many 17607
interp many 45905
builder many 2827
```